# How to run complex queries in Parse SDK

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

I have a devices table in Parse DB where I list the users' devices. Every row has a pointer to the `_User` class. The document also includes the `last_accessed` date.

**Device Collection**

```
+----------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| objectId | device_type | last_accessed            | user Pointer <_User> |
+----------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
| dfsQs0X  | iPhone      | 2020-05-21T18:30:22.761Z | eFjbWQdC1a           |
+----------+-------------+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

**User Collection**

```
+------------+-------------------+------------+
| objectId   | email             | isVerified |
+------------+-------------------+------------+
| eFjbWQdC1a | testuser@test.com | true       |
+------------+-------------------+------------+
```

**Note**: users can have multiple devices.

I'm looking for a solution to **count** the total **unique** verified accounts (`isVerified = true`) that have accessed their devices in the last 7 days (for analytics purposes).

**What I have tried**

```js
async function getActiveAccounts() {
  // Active Accounts are those who logged in to the App within the last 7 days
  const today = new Date();
  const startDate = new Date(today);
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);

  const query = new Parse.Query("Device").greaterThan("last_accessed", startDate);
  return query.count();
}
```

However, this code returns the number of devices but doesn't filter by unique verified users. How can I change the query to output the count of unique verified users that have at least one device logged-in in the last 7 days

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is `distinct`

```
async function getActiveAccounts() {
  // Active Accounts are those who logged in to the App within the last 7 days
  const today = new Date();
  const startDate = new Date(today);
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);

  const query = new Parse.Query("Device").greaterThan("last_accessed", startDate);
  query.select("objectId")//count isn't available on distinct queries, so just select the objectId as the only data to retrieve
  query.limit(10000)//make this is high as is reasonable
  var devices = await query.distinct("user");
  return devices.length;
}
```

This is one way to do it, but you could also use an aggregation pipeline.

**Edit:**

Here is an example using an aggregation pipeline.

```
async function getActiveAccounts() {
  // Active Accounts are those who logged in to the App within the last 7 days
  const today = new Date();
  const startDate = new Date(today);
  startDate.setDate(startDate.getDate() - 7);
  var pipeline = [
    {match:last_accessed: {$gt: startDate}},
    {group:{objectId:"$objectId", uniqueUsers:{$addToSet:"$_p_user"}}},
    {project:{objectId:null, count: {$size:"$uniqueUsers"}}}
  ];
  const q = new Parse.Query("Device");
  var result = await q.aggregate(pipeline);
  console.log(result);
}
```

keep in mind that in order to use `aggregate` you have to be using masterKey. If you're doing this in Cloud Code, then that would mean you'd do `q.aggregate(pipeline, {useMasterKey:true}}` instead of what's in the snippet.

Comment: Thanks @LulzCow, I forgot to mention that I already saw `distinct` in the Parse documentation. However, it seems to me that distinct is a quite expensive operation and I only want to retrieve the count. In addition, the `query.limit` is something I would rather avoid. Can you show an example with aggregation pipeline, please?

Comment: I will try to do that when I have time, but generally speaking `count` operations are more expensive than finds. I understand wanting to avoid limits, because they are arbitrary and introduce the possibility for bugs as your dataset grows, but this is probably the easiest solution. Aggregation should be the best solution though. If I haven't responded with an answer in a few days, mention me and I'll get back to this

Comment: Thanks LulzCow, any news about this?

Comment: @Skoltz check out my edit. You can read explanations of Parse aggregate queries here https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#aggregate